# The question is simple. I simply want to update name and address state using onChange event Handler

Tags: reactjs

The moment when i start typing on my textarea input, it becomes **undefined undefined undefined**.
The name field is updating the state but the address field didn't. So how to update the address state from onChange event handler?

```
constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
        users: {
            name: '',
            address: '',
        },
    }
    this.getOneUser = this.getOneUser.bind(this);
    this.onChangeHandler = this.onChangeHandler.bind(this);
    this.onSubmitHandler = this.onSubmitHandler.bind(this);
}
async getOneUser(){
    try{
        const {id} = this.props.match.params;
        const res = await fetch(`http://localhost:3003/users/${id}`);
        const data = await res.json();
        const {name, address} = data;
        this.setState({users: {name, address}}, () => console.log(this.state));
    }catch(err){
        console.error(err.message);
    }
}
async onSubmitHandler(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    const {id} = this.props.match.params;
    const {history} = this.props.match;
    try{
        const res = await fetch(`http://localhost:3003/users/${id}`, {
            method: 'PUT',
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
            body: JSON.stringify(this.state.users)
        });
        if(!res.ok) throw new Error(`could not fetch`);
        const data = await res.json();
        this.props.history.push('/');
    }catch(err){
        console.error(`${err.message}`);
    }
}
onChangeHandler(e){
    const {name, value} = e.target;
    this.setState({
        users: {...this.state.users, [name]:value}
    });
};
render(){
    const addr =  this.state.users.address;
    return <div>
        <input type='text' name='name' value={this.state.users.name} onChange={e => this.onChangeHandler(e)} className="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" />
    
        <textarea name='address' value={`${addr.street}, ${addr.city}, ${addr.zipcode}`} onChange={e => this.onChangeHandler(e)} className="form-control" placeholder="Address" id="floatingTextarea">
        </textarea>
    </div>
```

[image: Here is the Screenshot]

Comment: Shouldn't the value for the textarea be ```<textarea name='address' value={`${this.state.users.address.street}, ${this.state.users.address.city}, ${this.state.users.address.zipcode}`} onChange={e => this.onChangeHandler(e)} className="form-control" placeholder="Address" id="floatingTextarea">```
??

Comment: because you have not defined `addr` variable, but use it in value of `textarea`

Comment: How is this code not throwing an "Cannot access X of undefined" error when accessing `addr.street`? Is this full and complete code?

Comment: addr is already defined. Now i updated the above code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle the address case separately in `onChangeHandler`. You can map the first three comma-separated values to your `address` object and ignore others.

```
  onChangeHandler(e) {
    const { name, value } = e.target;

    if (name === "address") {
      const [street = "", city = "", zipcode = ""] = value.split(",");
      this.setState({
        users: {
          ...this.state.users,
          [name]: {
            street: street.trim(),
            city: city.trim(),
            zipcode: zipcode.trim()
          }
        }
      });
    } else {
      this.setState({
        users: { ...this.state.users, [name]: value }
      });
    }
  }
```

Remove the value you have set and give an informative placeholder.

```
<textarea
     name="address"
     onChange={(e) => this.onChangeHandler(e)}
     className="form-control"
     placeholder="street, city, zipcode"
     id="floatingTextarea"
></textarea>
```

Code sandbox => https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-frog-snv8t?file=/src/App.js